# How do i use Internal storage for different activity

Tags: android

Below page is the one having data i want to save from user.
How do I make this data to be read on next activity having a `editText` of text view?

And is this Code correct?

**AddMoney.class**

```
public class AddMoney extends AppCompatActivity {
Button b1;
EditText et;
enter code here
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_money);
    b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b1);
    et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et);

    b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            saveData();
            AlertDialog.Builder b = new AlertDialog.Builder(AddMoney.this);
            b.setIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
            int val = Integer.parseInt(et.getText().toString());
            b.setTitle("MONEY ADDED");
            String msg = "₹" + val + " has been added in your wallet";
            b.setMessage(msg);
            b.setCancelable(false);
            b.setPositiveButton("OK",null);                   
            AlertDialog d = b.create();
            d.show();
        }
    });

}

public void saveData() {
    try {
        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = openFileOutput("Expenses.txt", MODE_PRIVATE);
        fileOutputStream.write(et.getText().toString().getBytes());
        fileOutputStream.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: why do you want to save it externally? Use `SharedPreferences`

Answer (score 0):

As a better approach you can make use of `SharedPreference` as SripadRaj suggested.

on the first activity,where you save the data:

```
SharedPreference sp =getSharedPreferences("app_package_name", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
sp.putString("expense",et.getText().toString());
sp.apply();
```

On another activity:

```
SharedPreference sp =getSharedPreferences("app_package_name", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String expense = sp.getString("expense","0.0");
```